# How does anxiety cause chest pain?

Tags: pain

An acute instance of anxiety can cause a sudden sharp chest pain for a very brief period of time.  What is the mechanism behind anxiety leading to chest pain?

Is the pain coming from the heart itself, or surrounding muscles?  What structure is in pain and what is the physiology behind it?

Comment: you mean pain similar to a heart attack?

Comment: I would also notice that I think that this pain you're talking about is related to the more well-known feeling of heaviness in the chest in the period of depression. Maybe this is the same thing. Or maybe not.. however, I would like to know.